# How to configure network interfaces prioritization via policy-routing?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ipv6

I have two ipv6 only interfaces(eth1 and eth2) which are connected to switch. These interfaces get routes to main route table via RA(route advertisement) messages. The RA messages, sent by switch, has no metric, so, on target, received routes have same (1024) metric and I cant change it. But I need eth1 to have higher priority than eth2. So, how can I do this using policy based routing?